# How to configure the eslint extension in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

The [vscode eslint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) says:

> ## Configuration Options
>
> - `eslint.enable`: enable/diable eslint. Is enabled by default.
> - `eslint.options`: an option bag as defined by the ESLint API here. Defaults to an empty option bag.

I cannot figure out where to configure the eslint extension? Searching `configure` in the commands results in nothing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add extension-level configuration in the VSCode `settings.json` file. Open this through the command palette:

- Press <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Type "user settings"
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Add the rules in `eslint.options` like this, according to the [ESLint documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/):

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "eslint.options": {
        "rules": {
            "quotes": [2, "double"]
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can add this to workspace-level configuration by opening "workspace settings" through the command palette. This will create a `./vscode/settings.json` file in your project.

Comment: hmm the example is not quite valid -- I just learned that the `eslint.options` are the for the [CLIEngine](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#cliengine) and not the [`.eslintrc`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/formatters/index.html#eslintrc)

Comment: Do you mean the link on the extension documentation should not be pointing at http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#cliengine?

Comment: See Erich Gammas comment on this [vscode-eslint pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/pull/4).

Comment: This option seems to work to add or override global rules, but not sure its intended to do so.  Seems like it does belong to CLI Engine https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/373