# Personal ESLint rule overrides

Tags: eslint

I work at a smallish tech company where linting is not a very high priority. We have an `eslintConfig` specified in our `package.json`, with some basic rule extensions. There are a few specific rules I want to enable to warn me on my machine only, but I don't want to include them in the project config since I know my coworkers will complain. My goal is to be able to see these lint warnings whenever I'm working near them so I can quickly touch them up. Is there a way I can add these rules so only my local instance of ESLint applies them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for now is put some override rules in my VSCode ESLint options. These settings are specific to my machine's instance of VSCode and lets me include extra rules locally. It would still be nice for this to be included with the ESLint package itself, though.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756083/4468084