# Is there a way to configure eslint in VSCode to support typesRoot types for JavaScript in HTML files?

Tags: javascript, eslint, typescript-typings, typescript-eslint

I'm using a `jsconfig.json` like this

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@webgpu/types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "build",
    ".",
    ".eslintrc.js",
  ]
}
```

and an `eslintrc.js` file like this

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: ['./jsconfig.json'],
    extraFileExtensions: ['.html'],
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'eslint-plugin-html',
    'eslint-plugin-optional-comma-spacing',
    'eslint-plugin-one-variable-per-var',
    'eslint-plugin-require-trailing-comma',
  ],
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'],
  rules: {
    ...
  },
};
```

The important part is this line

```
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@webgpu/types", "./node_modules/@types"]
```

It adds the webgpu types and I can see that's working in VSCode for a javascript file

[image]

But it's not working for JavaScript inside HTML files

[image]

Is it possible to get it to include knowledge of the types for JavaScript inside HTML files?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that VSCode utilizes its 'html-language-features' service for HTML files, and not its JS or TS language services - subsequently a jsconfig.json configuration is not going to affect HTML files. There isn't a way around this unless you recompile the service yourself with amendments or request they implement the feature.

You can see how this works in action by trying to use JSDoc annotations that allow you specify types within JS files. If you implement the code below you'll see the types pass through successfully into the 'main.js' file, however if you copy the code specified in 'main.js' and paste it within script tags in an HTML file the types do not pass through.

Code from the official Typescript docs: [JSDoc @type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#type)

```
// @filename: types.d.ts
export type Pet = {
  name: string,
};
 
// @filename: main.js
/**
 * @param {import("./types").Pet} p
 */
function walk(p) {
  console.log(`Walking ${p.name}...`);  // p.name has type 'string'
}
```

Incidentally you can use the JSDoc annotations to specify types manually, that does work. However as you can see below there is no linting occurring, so it's not of much use anyway.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It seems like the html-langauge-server could/should be updated with options to use the JS language services for script tags. In fact that would be super useful for other language-serves like markdown for when I'm typing code examples. For my particular needs I write lots of single file .html examples for WebGL/WebGPU/Three.js. Keeping them in a single file makes them way more convenient than splitting them up but it means none of the completions work for three.js nor WebGPU (a standard part of the browser now)

Comment: Being able to nest language-servers would also be super helpful for inline shaders in C++, Rust, JavaScript, TypeScript, Python, etc. Probably for SQL stuff as well

Comment: Researching it I found this article about [embedded langauges](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages). That document claims the html-lanaguage-server calls out to the css-language-server for css and it would seem it calls out to the javascript-lanauge-server for JavaScript which suggests the issues are configuration, not the fact that the top level is the html-language-server.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of @SS87

You can use JSDoc annotations to specify types manually, but there is no linting occurring, so it's not as useful as it could be ([eslint extention in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737094/how-to-configure-the-eslint-extension-in-vscode)).

To make ESLint work with JavaScript inside HTML files, you may need to use a workaround
once you installed it in your `eslintrc.js` file, add `eslint-plugin-html` in the plugins array:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'eslint-plugin-html',
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
};
```

In the `parserOptions`, add `.html` in the `extraFileExtensions` we add:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: ['./jsconfig.json'],
    extraFileExtensions: ['.html'],
  },
  // ...
};
```

In your `jsconfig.json` file, add `"typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@webgpu/types", "./node_modules/@types"]` in the `compilerOptions` object:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@webgpu/types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  // ...
}
```

This configuration will help make ESLint aware of the types when dealing with JavaScript inside HTML files [i followed the official tutorial](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files).

Comment: I have all of those settings in my project but it's not showing the types in HTML files for me. [Here's a minimal github repo](https://github.com/greggman/vscode-html--types/). Maybe you can spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @gman try to modify the include array inside jsconfing.json like this: `"include": [
    ".",
    ".eslintrc.js",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.html"
  ]`

Comment: that didn't help. Still doesn't work ([updated the git repo with your changes](https://github.com/greggman/vscode-html--types/commit/71bf48fcb58039c6beb050c001648b3631fb3a2c))

Comment: ok can you check the  output of ESLint in VSCode? on View > Output, and select ESLint from the dropdown. you can also try `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init` to re-initializing ESLint.

Comment: I used `eslint --init` to setup the minimal repo. I'm also not sure what you expect me to see in the output. It doesn't say anything special. Just  ESlint server started, server running in node ..., server running, library loaded from ..... There are no other messages. Are you saying [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ4yel.png) works for you?

Comment: let's try this : Press `Ctrl+,`  open the settings
Search for `eslint.validate`
Click on Edit in `settings.json` add html in the array`"eslint.validate": [
   "javascript",
   "javascriptreact",
   "typescript",
   "typescriptreact",
   "html"
]`

Comment: no change. still no webgpu types in html. You haven't said if the git repo works for you.

Comment: no it did not that's why i was tring something new.

Comment: @gman Some users have reported that they needed to add `"eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true` to their VSCode settings to get ESLint to work properly [Source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1736).

Comment: othen then this maybe deactivate all the other extentions to see if there is a conflict?